# Fill 2D Vector of type Base class with derived class

Tags: c++, vector, derived-class

I have a base class, Organism, with 2 derived classes, Ant and Doodlebug.  This is for a predator-prey problem.  I want to have a 2d vector of type Base class, but be able to assign elements of the derived class. The idea being that this will represent the state of the world in a 20 X 20 character map where if the element is the base, the char is ' ', whereas it will be a different char if the element is derived.

I read about how to do it if its one dimensional vector, but I couldn't find the proper syntax of declaring a pointer to a 2d vector. Here's what I have, I got errors if I tried to put:

```
vector < vector<Organism*> > state(20, vector<Organism*>(20));
```

but this is what compiles but prints out a field of numbers instead of the characters:

```
vector < vector<Organism> > state(20, vector<Organism>(20));
string line;
int stateline = 0;

while(getline(ini_state_file, line))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
    {
        if(line[i] == 'o')
            state[stateline][i] = Ant();
        else if(line[i] == 'X')
            state[stateline][i] = Doodlebug();
    }
    stateline++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// or some smart_ptr instead native pointer.
vector<vector<Organism*> > state(20, vector<Organism*>(20));
string line;
int stateline = 0;

while(getline(ini_state_file, line))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
    {
        if(line[i] == 'o')
            state[stateline][i] = new Ant();
        else if(line[i] == 'X')
            state[stateline][i] = new Doodlebug();
    }
    stateline++;
}
```

Not forget to free memory. When your work with this vector will be ended, you must free memory, example.

```
for (int i = 0; i < state.size(); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < state[i].size(); ++j)
    {
        delete state[i][j];
    }
}
```

Or use iterators or algorithm as for_each instead indexes.
 If you want to use smart pointers, you shouldn`t free memory.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Though when I try to print out the vector, using state[i][j]->getOrg_char(), I just get a bunch of numbers instead of the characters I'm looking for.

Comment: You try to print out of vector, before free memory?

Comment: yea right after the while statement, I tried this to make sure everything was stored properly:  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            cout << state[i][j]->getOrg_char();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

Comment: Strange. http://liveworkspace.org/code/8a428e6643e3ef43b77b4e9f63a031d0 so this example work. So, if state[stateline][i] not equal to o or X, object will not created, so in vector in this place will be null pointer (or pointer that refer to garbage).

Comment: Yea I thought about that and already added another line to the while statement saying if its not 'o' or 'X'  state[i][j] = new organism.  What happens to you're code if you try to add organism objects to the vector?

Comment: Not working on my end using the for loop, keep getting problems trying to use the for_each loop. :(

Comment: Never mind, I had the accessor function set as int not char!  Thanks for your help!